# Setting up PySide/Qt for GUI development

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I have been trying to setup PySide/Qt for use with Python3.3. I have installed

```
PySide-1.2.0.win32-py3.3.exe
```

that I took from [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows) and I have installed

```
qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-vs2010
```

that I took from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

I generated `.py` files from `.ui` files (that I made using QtDesigner) using `pyside-uic.exe` [as is explained in PySide Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtCreator_and_PySide).

Making `.py` files was working when I was using Qt5.1/QtCreator. I stopped using it when I found that I need to use Qt4.8 [as explained on Qt-forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30114/). With Qt4.8 it isn't working.

- I want to develop GUI using PySide.
- I want a drag-and-drop interface for making a skeleton GUI so I am using QtDesigner.
- I am on Windows 7

I want to package the GUI developed into .exe files using cx-freeze.

**My problem in short**
What are the correct tools to use to make `.ui` with QtDesigner? How to convert them to `.py` files for use in Python using PySide?

cx_freeze is able to make my normal files to `.exe` Can it be used to convert the GUI made by Qt/PySide into `.exe` files?  Would Qt be needed on other computers where the `.exe` of the GUI is distributed or would it be self-contained?

---

I used

```
cxfreeze testGUI.py  --include-modules=PySide
```

to make the exe and related files. A directory `dist` was created with many files. On running nothing happened. So I used command line to find out the reason. The errors are

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "testGUI.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1558, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
    pysideDir = _utils.get_pyside_dir()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 87, in get_pyside_dir
    return _get_win32_case_sensitive_name(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 83, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
    path = _get_win32_long_name(_get_win32_short_name(s))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 58, in _get_win32_short_name
    raise WinError()
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Anyone knows what this stacktrace means?

There is a lot of `win32` in here. But I have Windows 7 64-bit. I am using 32-bit Python and all modules were installed 32-bit. Could that cause a problem? I don't think it should as other exe I made for simple Python scripts were executing fine.

Comment: you can create your UI with Qt Creator.

Comment: @Reza But the problem is how to properly use the `.ui` files with Python. Do I convert them to Python classes using pyside-uic or do I need to dynamically load them? What needs to be done for converting the resulting application into a functional exe? I use cxfreeze normally and it works but the exe with GUI didn't work. I am just stumped.

Comment: I don't know exactly what thing causes your error, but in C++ Qt generates related `.cpp` file of UI, then compile it in project, take a time for search in Qt documentation for Loading `.ui` files directly if it is possible.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Are you using and deploying custom widgets?

Comment: @cfi I am just starting out with PySide and GUI in Python so not yet. I just wanted to get these details out of the way before I try to make use of any particular toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarded FileNotFoundError, I had a problem packaging a python 3 application with this for a few days. On a windows 7 64 bit machine it worked fine. When I built it on win7 32bit and tried to run the .exe file, I got all those file errors. After seeing this thread I checked the versions of pyside. On the win64 it was 1.1.2 on the win32 it was 1.2.0
I uninstalled pyside 1.2.0 on win32 and downloaded and installed the 1.1.2 win32 version. It now works ok.
This could be a stop gap measure until 1.2.1 is released.

Answer (score 5):

This error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

will be fixed in next pyside release (1.2.1). It will be released in next week.

btw: in case you don't want to generate custom bindings, you don't need to install qt, pyside installer contains all qt libraries and devel tools.

Comment: I have heard that on qt-forums too. Can you clarify where exactly are the dev tools? I tried to find Qt designer but there was none present till I installed Qt itself. I wanted a drag-and-drop interface for making the GUI. What exactly does custom bindings mean?

Comment: designer, linguist, lrelease, lupdate, pyside-rcc and pyside-lupdate are in same folder as pyside libs, on my sustem this is the path c:\Python27_64\Lib\site-packages\PySide-1.2.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\PySide. Custom binding is when you want to generate python wrapper for your c++ class with shiboken.

Comment: I huge thanks for this. I finally found where the designer, linguist etc. were present. I had already installed-unistalled Qt/PySide 3 times and thought it was a matter of sequence. Maybe some files accidentally replaced other files. I can wait one week. Can you tell me where exactly is PySide community present generally? Tried QtForums and didn't get much there.

Comment: Here is home page http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide and active mailing list http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/pyside

Comment: Where did you read that this was an error to be fixed in the next release? I tried to find it but there isn't any such message except on an issue on github which noone seems to be reading.

Comment: you need to search pyside mailing list for "cxfreeze and PySide 1.2.0". And here is the fix from J.B.Mohler: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,60935. I'm reading messages on github :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar (however I'm in the progress of migrating from PyQt to PySide).

You should use pyside-uic to generate the code for the GUI after creating the UI files in QtCreator (If this were PyQt "pyuic gui.ui > gui.py" would produce the desired code, I assume pyside-uic has a similar behaviour). I then subclass this generated code to customise the user interface.

Yes, you can use cx_freeze with PyQt/PySide, you'll want to include PySide in the "includes" item in the build options.

Yes, you can create a completely self-contained executable - you won't need Python, Qt or anything else.

Here's the build I use from my PySide GUI application.

```
__author__ = 'AlexM'
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import MyPySideGui
import PySide, os

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

QGifRelDir = "imageformats\qgif4.dll"
PySideDir = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(PySide.__file__),"plugins"))

shortcut_table = [
    ("App Shortcut",                 # Shortcut
     "ProgramMenuFolder",            # Directory_
     "MyPySideGUI",                  # Name
     "TARGETDIR",                    # Component_
     "[TARGETDIR]MyPySideApp.exe",   # Target
     None,                           # Arguments
     None,                           # Description
     None,                           # Hotkey
     None,                           # Icon
     None,                           # IconIndex
     None,                           # ShowCmd
     'TARGETDIR'                     # WkDir
     )
]

build_exe_options = {
    "include_files" : ["documentTemplate.html", "loading.gif", (os.path.join(PySideDir,QGifRelDir), QGifRelDir)],
    "packages" : ["CustomHelperPackage", "AnotherCustomPackage", "MyPySideGui"],
    "includes" : ["PySide"],
    "excludes" : ["tkinter"],
    'optimize': 2,
}

# Now create the table dictionary
msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table}

# Change some default MSI options and specify the use of the above defined tables
bdist_msi_options = {'data': msi_data}

executables = [ Executable("MyPySideGui.py", base = base) ]

setup(
    name = "MyFirstPySideApplication",
    version = str(MyPySideGui.version),
    description = "MyPySideApp.exe Demonstrates PySide guis.",
    options = {
        "build_exe": build_exe_options,
        "bdist_msi": bdist_msi_options
    },
    executables = executables
)
```

This example might be slightly complicated for you, but you can find simpler examples on the cx_freeze project homepage.

I'm not getting the issues you or the other answer are getting, but then I'm using Python 3.3.1 with PySide 1.1.2.

Comment: I actually solved the problem about converting .py to .ui files. It seems that `distribute` somehow stops working after installing PySide. Can you give an example of how to use cx_freeze to specify the includes? I have been using `cx_freeze-quickstart` batch file present. It doesn't give much options and I couldn't understand cx_freeze wiki explanation.

Comment: Updated the question. I think this is the same problem that happened last time.

Comment: I'll post the build script I use with cx_freeze tomorrow.

Comment: Updated answer with build script.

Answer (score 0):

PySide 1.2.1 was released. It has fixed the error. I checked it by installing the new version and using cx_freeze.

No error in packaging with cx_freeze 4.3.1(32-bit version for Python 3.3) used with Python 3.3.2(32-bit) and PySide 1.2.1(32-bit) on Windows 7(64-Bit). I used the command written in the question to package it. It worked successfully.