# How to deploy a Pyside application? (runtime requirements?)

Tags: python, linux, deployment, installation, pyside

I am starting to learn Python. I'm going to write a Pyside application (my first). I hope it will run on platforms ranging from recent releases of Kubuntu to older Linux Mint releases (in particular, Linux Mint ***9***).

I searched around for "pyside runtime requirements" and didn't find much... also searched for "deploy a pyside application" without any better luck.

I found the following info at [qt-project](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Linux):

> PySide core dev team, maintains a PPA repository for Ubuntu. Currently, up-to-date packages are available for versions from 10.04 (Lucid) up to 11.10 (Oneiric).

I see the instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pyside
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pyside
```

What I don't see is whether there are other runtime requirements. I also don't see info about how I would deploy my Pyside application. I assume I could possibly just have a script that runs the 3 lines above (and that verifies Python is installed on the system, which is almost a certainty for the Linux platforms I'm targeting).

But I have zero experience with this, so I would appreciate clarification on this. How exactly do I deploy a Pyside application to these target platforms? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, use cxfreeze. Long answer you may wanna have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787315/setting-up-pyside-qt-for-gui-development). As far as I understood by asking the question there is currently some kind-a problem with PySide that is going to be fixed in next PySide update (1.2.1). After that cxfreeze can be used.

**Update 1**

You can take a look [at PySide on github](https://github.com/PySide). There are relevant repos for packaging.

Comment: Thank you. Some of that seems helpful. The link to the question seems completely Windows-centric. I don't want to generate an .exe. I didn't understand anything I saw on github.